# How does the dx2-y2 orbital bond with four ligands in square planar metal-metal complexes

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure, crystal-field-theory

I understand that the complex [Re2Cl8]2-  has a bond order of 4 between the ruthenium ions. The bond comprises of sigma interactions between
Dz2 orbitals, two sets of pi interactions between dxz and d yz, and  delta interactions  between the dxy orbitals of the two ruthenium ions. My textbook says that the dx2-y2 orbitals remain for the metal ligand bonding.
How do you fit 16 electrons from 8 ligands into two orbitals,
I thought you could only fit two electrons in an orbital.
Are the dx2-y2 orbitals forming hybrid orbitals with the empty 4s orbitals ?[image]

Comment: Eight of the 16 electrons are in the quadruple bond.

Comment: If you understand how a normal triple bond between 2 carbons has a bond order of 3, then it should be pretty clear why adding a $\delta$ bond in addition to this creates a bond order of 4.

Comment: Zhe, sure I understand that part, but its not quite what im stuck on

Comment: gsurfer04, yeah I agree that 8 electrons are in the quadruple bond, but we have to account for 24 electrons, 4 from each rhenium ion and 2 from each of the 8 ligands. If the dz2, dxz, dyz and dxy are used to form the quadruple bond, where are the remaining 16 electrons going, as all we have left over are two dx2-y2 orbitals which can hold a total of 4 electrons. So where do we put the other 8?